# Fastlane - Missing required icon file

Tags: ios, xcode

Estoy intentando ejecutar el comando

```
fastlane deliver
```

Sin embargo, tras probar todas las respuestas de todos los foros que he encontrado, me sigue dando el mismo error que es el siguiente:

> [13:44:26]: [Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90022: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 10.0."
>
> [13:44:26]: [Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '167x167' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions supporting iPad Pro."
>
> [13:44:26]: [Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 10.0."
>
> [13:44:26]: Transporter transfer failed.

A pesar de que tengo todos los iconos, tienen los nombres correctos, son .png y se encuentran en el archivo .json. ¿Alguien sabe cómo solucionar el problema?

Gracias.

Comment: El problema parece ser precisamente el tamaño, ya que se así existan todos los íconos, con nombres correctos, en .png y se encuentren en el JSON, generarán errores si no tienen las dimensiones EXACTAS mencionadas en la advertencia, 120x120, 167x167, 152x152....

Comment: Sí, la cuestión es que los tamaños también son los exactos, lo he comprobado varias veces... es una cuestión muy extraña

Comment: En algún momento tuve un problema directamente con iTunnes Connect al subir los screenshots e íconos de la aplicación en exactamente el formato, tamaño y nombre requerido por Apple, y lo solucioné generando estos recursos con una herramienta diferente bajo exactamente las mismas especificaciones y funcionó. Quizás el error lo está generando directamente 'fastlane' y no iTunnes, sin embargo merece la pena intentar la re-generación de íconos con otra herramienta diferente.

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a probarlo y lo pongo aquí

Answer (score 0):

Hace poco estuve lidiando con el mismo problema, realmente no me preocupé mucho por entender el origen del mismo.
Simplemente encontré en varios foros que se trata de alguna imagen que estás colocando cuyas dimensiones no encajan según lo que Apple requiere.

Te recomiendo que utilices esta página https://makeappicon.com/, donde subes el ícono en resolución 1024x1024 y la página te genera automáticamente los iconos tanto para iOS como para Android.

Dentro del **.zip** que genera la página (en la cual debes proporcionar un correo para descargar dicho archivo .zip) está una carpeta llamada **"AppIcon.appiconset"** la cual debes colocar dentro de 
tus "Assets.xcassets", reemplazando el archivo **"AppIcon"** que seguramente ya tiene tu proyecto (a menos que hayas cambiado el nombre).

Una vez hagas esto no deberías presentar más problemas, lo mejor de todo es que es rápido y fácil. También existen otras páginas y programas que hacen lo mismo, pero la que menciono es la que más utilizo.

Espero haber sido de ayuda. Gracias por leer mi respuesta.